# Get mathematical expressions (single letters, numbers, equations...) using regex (in python)

Tags: python, regex

I'm new to regex and would like to match (in my python-programm) mathematical expressions in a string using regex. Mathematical expressions are for me (now) single letters, numbers and expressions between square brackets. So e.g. for the given sentence (=string)

> "*Let f(a) in the variable a be 100 in the expression
>   [[f(a)=a+1]].*"

I'd like to get something like:

> [f(a),a,100,f(a)=a+1]

I managed to get

1, the expression in the squared brackets using [[(.*?)]]
2, single letters and numbers using \b[0-9a-zA-Z]{1}\b and
3, numbers generally using \d+

, but not to get everything with one regular expression.
May someone help with an appropriate regex-module or would it be better to solve this problem in a pythonic way?

Comment: Perhaps for your example data  [`(?<=\[\[)[)(0-9a-z=+]+(?=]])|\b[a-z]\([a-z+]\)|\b[0-9a-zA-Z]\b`](http://rextester.com/SQBNSM60733)

Comment: You can definitely use regexes for this problem but you may also want to look at something like https://github.com/erikrose/parsimonious for parsing mathematical expressions.

Comment: I have some questions:  `f(a)` is not inside brackets. Is that a typo? Should it be matched? Also, what happens with sentences like `I have a variable called v` That may match both 'v' and 'a'

Comment: Yes, f(a) should also be matched. I made this now using \b[a-z]*\([a-z]*\). Cause I'm using german language matching v and a is ok.

Answer (score 2):

This will capture your mathematical expressions disregarding the number of brackets `(?<=\[)[^\[]*?(?=\])`

Check a demo here [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4CfdF5/1/)

To get a list in python with your math expressions, you can use the following code:

```
p = re.compile('(?<=\[)[^\[]*?(?=\])')

p.findall('YOUR TEXT HERE')
```

Comment: Thanks @Jorge. Thats working nearly perfect. Just one thing: there should only be matched (non-empty) expressions between exactly two square brackets. That works (in python) with `...re.compile('(?<=\[\[)(.+?)(?=\]\])|\d+')...`. But when I extend the regex e.g. catching the numbers, following regex is not working: `...re.compile('(?<=\[\[)(.+?)(?=\]\])|\d+')...`. Why could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it. Thanks to everyone! You made my day.

Thats my regular expression:

```
'(?<=[ ][[]{2}).*?(?=[]]{2}[ .!?])|\d+|\b[a-zA-Z0-9{+-}]*\([a-zA-Z0-9{+-}]*\)|\b[a-zA-Z]\b'
```